# how to change type ajax call to controller of option "serviceUrl" in ajax autocomplete jquery devbridge with CodeIgniter?

Tags: codeigniter, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete

I'm using ajax autocomplete tutorial from http://www.devbridge.com/projects/autocomplete/jquery.

I wanna change query of it to get exactly when I fill input text. So, I need to write a function in model such as: "select username from user where username LIKE "search_string%" ".

But now **my first problem** is, it sends request to server: `http://localhost/project_name/controller_name/function_name?query=search_string`.

In CodeIgniter must be: `http://localhost/project_name/controller_name/function_name/search_string` .

**My second problem**, how can I get and pass search_string from script initialize autocomplete?

MY HTML:

```
<input class="input-short" style="width: 150px;" type="text" id="search_by_user"  />
```

MY SCRIPT:

```
var options, a;
$(document).ready(function(){
    var search_string = ???; //how to get??
    options = {
        serviceUrl:'controller_name/function_name/' + search_string, //**how to get search_string???**
        onSelect: function(suggestion) {
            alert('You selected ' + suggestion.value);    
        } 
    };
    a = $('#search_by_user').autocomplete(options);   
});
```

How to fix those?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed my problems, but data that contains values for callback function when data is selected always null. What's up? 
MY SCRIPT:

```
var options, a;

$(document).ready(function(){
    options = {
        serviceUrl:'controller_name/function_test',
        onSelect: function(suggestion) {
            alert('You selected ' + suggestion.value + ', ' + suggestion.data);    
        } 
    };
    a = $('#search_by_user').autocomplete(options);   
});
```

MY FUNCTION IN CONTROLLER :

```
public function function_test() {
        $query = isset($_GET['query']) ? $_GET['query'] : FALSE;
        //$query = 'te';
        if($query) {
            $found = $this->model_name->get_list($query);
            $suggestions = array();
            $data = array();
            foreach($found as $row) {
                $suggestions[] = $row['strfound'];
                $data[] = $row['id'];
            }
            $response = array(
                'query' => $query,
                'suggestions' => $suggestions,
                'data' => $data,
            );
            echo json_encode($response);
        }
}
```

When I echo $response to browser to test, I got data. 
But when I make real, suggestion.data always returns null. Why? 
EX: I got alert the same as "You selected teo, null".

Comment: what is your JSON output format ? it has to be like that https://github.com/devbridge/jQuery-Autocomplete#response-format but proms with quotes like 'suggestions' as you have it.. maybe this plugin to FF will helpful https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/jsonview/

Answer (score 1):

```
remove data[]
just    
$suggestions[] = array('value'= $row['fildname'],'data'=>$row['id']);
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on your answer?

Comment: Please write in detail how your answer should be included to help the questioner. Thank you.